A model category whose Hammock localization gives the infinite category of infinite functors from differential graded algebras to simplicial sets
I have been reading a little bit of Homotopical Algebraic Geometry I: Topos theory by Toën and Vezzosi (HAG 1) (https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0207028) in the search of a specific result I am trying to understand.
I would like to find a model category $(C,W)$ whose Hammock localization $L_W(C)$ is equivalent as an infinite category to the infinite category of infinite functors $Fun^{\infty}(\mathrm{cdga}_\mathbb{K}^{\leq 0}, \mathrm{sSets})$ from the infinity category of differential graded algebras concentrated in negative degree over a field $\mathbb{K}$ of characteristic $0$ to the infinity category of simplicity sets.
It seems to me that, according to the sentence in the proof of Theorem 4.7.1 in HAG 1, this is explained in Theorem 2.3.5 of HAG 1. It would seem that the model category I am searching is obtained through a Bousfield localization: I should consider the category of "standard" functors $Fun(\mathrm{cdga}_\mathbb{K}^{\leq 0}, \mathrm{sSets})$ equipped with its projective model structure, and then do a Bousfield localization with respect to the class of morphisms $\{ h_f \ , \ f \ \text{a weak equivalence} \}$, where
\begin{equation*}
h_{-} : \mathrm{cdga}_\mathbb{K}^{\leq 0} \to Fun(\mathrm{cdga}_\mathbb{K}^{\leq 0},\mathrm{Set}) \hookrightarrow Fun(\mathrm{cdga}_\mathbb{K}^{\leq 0}, \mathrm{sSets}) \end{equation*}
is the constant Yoneda embedding.
However, I am not able to understand why Theorem 2.3.5 is explaining that.
Moreover, I cannot understand why it is necessary to do the Bousfield localization to get a model for our infinity category of infinity functors.
Thank you very much for your help, and do not hesitate to ask if you believe I have not been sufficiently clear.

I'm thinking you mean infinity category, or ∞-category, not infinite category?
